# Guice: class- or instance-level binding annotations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Guice provides two variations of so-called **binding annotations**, which seem to really break down to class- and instance-level annotations:

"Class-level":

```
bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(Red.class).to(RedServiceImpl.class);

@Red
public class SomeService implements Service { ... }

Service redSvc = injector.getInstance(SomeService.class);
```

"Instance-level":

```
bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Blue").to(BlueServiceImpl.class);
@Blue blueSvc = injector.getInstance(Service.class);
```

When is one method preferential over the other? It seems that class-level annotations are more absolute/inflexible than instance-level. Pros/cons/caveats/pitfalls of either method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Your use of binding annotations is irregular.  You wouldn't typically annotate a local variable or a class, but rather fields and parameters.

Your first code example *will* cause the injector to return SomeService, but not because of your annotation or your binding, but because SomeService is a concrete implementation.  Had you asked for this instead:

```
Service redSvc = injector.getInstance(Service.class);
```

You will get an error:

```
1) No implementation for com.example.Service was bound.
  while locating com.example.Service
```

Your second example is also incorrect.  If you use `Names` to define a binding, you must use `@Named` to access that binding.  Using `@Blue` would cause a compiler error.  The correct usage would be `@Named(value="Blue")`.

The common best practice for a binding annotation is this:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno
```

In that case, both of these would be compile errors:

```
@Red // not allowed
public class SomeService implements Service { ... }

@Blue // not allowed
blueSvc = injector.getInstance(Service.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference is that in one case you bind for a whole annotation, and in the other case you bind to an annotation with specific arguments.  Not all annotations even take arguments, in which case, binding with the annotation class is perfectly normal.